# Has there been a computer search for a 5-chromatic unit distance graph?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

The existence of a 4-chromatic unit distance graph (e.g., [the Moser spindle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle)) establishes a lower bound of 4 for the chromatic number of the plane (see the [Nelson-Hadwiger problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem)).

Obviously, it would be nice to have an example of a *5-chromatic* unit distance graph. To the best of my knowledge, the existence of such a graph is open. Has there been any (documented) attempt to find such a graph through a computer search? For instance, has every $n$-vertex possibility been checked up to some $n$?

Comment: An interesting variation, which seems more amenable to computer search, is to look for non-4-colorable *almost*-unit distance graph. You can indeed ask for the chromatic number $\chi_\epsilon$ of the graph whose vertices are the points of the plane, and an edge joins two vertices if their distance is between $1$ and $1+\varepsilon$. Obviously $\chi_\varepsilon$ decreases when $\varepsilon\to 0$, but the limit is not known. It is not known if the limit is the chromatic number of the plane either.

Comment: @Benoit Do you have some references for almost-unit distance graphs?

Comment: @domotorp: no, I don't think it has been actually looked at (I have some lose ideas myself, but nothing written).

Comment: @Benoit I've just realized that $\chi_\varepsilon\ge 6$, as shown by the following simple argument. Divide the plane into a grid of length $\varepsilon$ and color each small square to the color of its center. If the original coloring avoided distances $1\pm \varepsilon$, then this new coloring will still avoid unit distances. Since each region is nice, at least 6 colors are needed because of this result: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316573900204

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As of this morning [there is a paper on the ArXiv](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.02385) claiming to show that there exists a 5-chromatic unit distance graph with $1567$ vertices.  The paper is written by non-mathematician Aubrey De Grey (of anti-aging fame), but it appears to be a serious paper.  Time will tell if it holds up to scrutiny.

EDIT: in fact, it must be the one with 1585 vertices, according to checkers, see https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2018/04/10/the-chromatic-number-of-the-plane-is-at-least-5/

Comment: You have to be kidding me!

Comment: It is computer checkable if the graph (including vertex locations) is available.  I don't think it should be dismissed out of hand, even though the result is quite surprising.

Comment: Some more information on Terence Tao's Google+ https://plus.google.com/+TerenceTao27/posts/QBxTFAsDeBp and also a new polymath project to improve on the example to make it easier to check https://polymathprojects.org/2018/04/10/polymath-proposal-finding-simpler-unit-distance-graphs-of-chromatic-number-5/

Comment: Very exciting! The paper seems to be using Mathematica; I wish it also made the 1567-vertex graph available in some format (like the DIMACS format). This would allow for a quick check of some of the claims.

Comment: The graph is now available in multiple formats (including DIMACS) here: https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2018/04/10/the-chromatic-number-of-the-plane-is-at-least-5/

Comment: @DustinG.Mixon Many thanks! I was about to run a SAT solver on it as well, but I see in your post that this has already been done, nice!

Comment: This is an amazing result! @Juho: It wouldn't hurt to run a different SAT solving program on it, as an independent check.

Comment: @TimothyChow treengeling finished with UNSAT result as well, as expected (or hoped). I can upload the files later on too if anyone is interested.

Comment: The link to Terence Tao's post on Google+ mentioned in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/739792) above is now broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20180410232108/https://plus.google.com/+TerenceTao27/posts/QBxTFAsDeBp).

Answer (score 10):

It depends how serious you require the search to be. ☺

When writing [this note](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.07023), I made a few attempts at experimenting in this direction, but I quickly came to the conclusion that either I didn't know how to approach the experimental problem, or that it was just too large to be feasible, or both.

I tried to concentrate on a particular set of graphs, namely the minimal $5$-chromatic subgraphs of $(\mathbb{F}_p)^2$ (with an edge between $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ iff $(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2=1$) for small $p$, because some of the remarks in the aforementioned note (esp. around prop. 5.3) suggest that this *might* be a good place to look.  But even there, I obviously got nowhere (although I can't say that I tried extremely hard).

Answer (score 8):

It is at least known that there is no 5-chromatic unit distance graph on at most 12 vertices [1, Theorem 4]. I don't know if something similar is known for larger values of $n$.

---

[1] [Pritikin, Dan. "All unit-distance graphs of order 6197 are 6-colorable." Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B 73.2 (1998): 159-163.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0095895698918196)